# How can I change the color of a UIImage?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uicolor

I want not to change the backgroundColor of an UIImage, but rather to change the color of the whole image.

But the problem is: I can only change the backgroundColor.

Comment: You really need to explain in more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: an image view shows an image, so what do you mean when you say "change the colour"?

Comment: edited my post. I hope it is understandable

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"triangle.png"];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, image.CGImage);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImage *flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage 
                                            scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];

yourUIImageView.image = flippedImage;
```

Comment: thank you so much. I had just problems with the statement imageView.image = img; but then change it to [testTest.newView setImage: img];

Comment: overwriting? what are you mean?

Comment: I have a png, which is a triangle. So if I use your method not the triangle get the color but also the background of the image. At the end there is no triangle but a square which has got the color red

Comment: I've edit answer, but you should expressed understandable in your question next time. It was really hard to understand what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just looking through this trying to understand it.  One question I have is how is it getting flipped to start?

Comment: Because of last two strings.

Comment: Great answer.  However this only selects the non-retina image, even on a retina device?

Comment: @nicktones: Remove the ".png" suffix from the given example. This allows the app to determine which image is appropriate instead of being told exactly which image to use (it would be akin to "triangle@2x.png").

Comment: The result is not good for retina screens... See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20750373/1670830 for a fix.

Answer (score 130):

The accepted answer is correct, but there is a much more **easy way** for `UIImageView`:

**Obj-C:**

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"];
theImageView.image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
[theImageView setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

**Swift 2:**

```
let theImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"foo")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate))
theImageView.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let theImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"foo")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate))
theImageView.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: Perfect answer, but can we just fill the inner frame with new color and not change border color of the `UIImage`?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar what do you mean by "border color"?

Comment: Image's border color. Suppose I have an image which have border color as gray. This gray color should not change but inner color should change.

Comment: @skywinder, is there any way to detect color and change specific color?
Like i have 2 color image white and red. i want to change only white portion of image. Is it possible?

Comment: @MrugeshTank with this method - no. it just create mask from image and fill it with color. So, you nedd some advanced image-processing libs for that.

Comment: @MrugeshTank `OpenCV` is most advanced library for that cases

Comment: Great Answer.  @Studie As this is more efficient answer, this should mark as accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you!  So easy!  I have updated this for a button below

Answer (score 12):

For swift 3.2 and 4

```
extension UIImageView{
    func changePngColorTo(color: UIColor){
        guard let image =  self.image else {return}
        self.image = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.tintColor = color
    }
}
```

Use :

```
self.yourImageView.changePngColorTo(color: .red)
```

Comment: That doesn't change the color of the UIImage. Rather the image view is rendering it with a different color.

Answer (score 8):

### Details

- Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

### Way 1. Extension UIImage

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40177870/4488252

```
extension UIImage {

    convenience init?(imageName: String) {
        self.init(named: imageName)
        accessibilityIdentifier = imageName
    }

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/40177870/4488252
    func imageWithColor (newColor: UIColor?) -> UIImage? {

        if let newColor = newColor {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)

            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
            context.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
            context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
            context.setBlendMode(.normal)

            let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
            context.clip(to: rect, mask: cgImage!)

            newColor.setFill()
            context.fill(rect)

            let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            newImage.accessibilityIdentifier = accessibilityIdentifier
            return newImage
        }

        if let accessibilityIdentifier = accessibilityIdentifier {
            return UIImage(imageName: accessibilityIdentifier)
        }

        return self
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 250, width: 40, height: 40))
view.addSubview(imageView)
// Set color
imageView.image = UIImage(imageName: "Apple")?.imageWithColor(newColor: UIColor.blue)
// Reset color
//imageView.image = imageView.image?.imageWithColor(newColor: nil)
```

### Way 2. Extension UIImageView

```
extension UIImageView {

    var imageColor: UIColor? {
        set (newValue) {
            guard let image = image else { return }
            if newValue != nil {
                self.image = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                tintColor = newValue
            } else {
                self.image = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
                tintColor = UIColor.clear
            }
        }
        get { return tintColor }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 250, width: 40, height: 40))
view.addSubview(imageView)
imageView.image = UIImage(imageName: "Apple")
// Set color
imageView.imageColor = UIColor.green
// Reset color
//imageView.imageColor = nil
```

### Full sample

> Do not forget to paste here all code which placed above

```
import UIKit

class ImageView: UIImageView {
    enum ImageColorTransformType {
        case none, imageExtension, imageViewExtension
    }
    var imageColorTransformType = ImageColorTransformType.none
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var colorSwitchButton: UIBarButtonItem?

    private var imageViews = [ImageView]()
    private var appleImage: UIImage { return UIImage(imageName: "apple")! }
    private var redAppleImage: UIImage { return UIImage(imageName: "red_apple")! }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createNewImageView(x: 40, y:100, image:appleImage, imageColorTransformType: .none)
        createNewImageView(x: 100, y:100, image:appleImage, imageColorTransformType: .imageExtension)
        createNewImageView(x: 160, y:100, image:appleImage, imageColorTransformType: .imageViewExtension)

        createNewImageView(x: 40, y:160, image:redAppleImage, imageColorTransformType: .none)
        createNewImageView(x: 100, y:160, image:redAppleImage, imageColorTransformType: .imageExtension)
        createNewImageView(x: 160, y:160, image:redAppleImage, imageColorTransformType: .imageViewExtension)

        let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "switch", style: .plain, target: self,
                                         action: #selector(colorSwitchButtonTouchedUpInside(_:)))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem
        colorSwitchButton = buttonItem
        useOriginalColors = false
    }

    private func createNewImageView(x:CGFloat, y: CGFloat, image: UIImage, imageColorTransformType: ImageView.ImageColorTransformType) {
        let imageView = ImageView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 40, height: 40))
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.imageColorTransformType = imageColorTransformType
        imageViews.append(imageView)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    private var _useOriginalColors = false
    private var useOriginalColors: Bool {
        set(value) {
            _useOriginalColors = value
            if (value) {
                navigationItem.title = "Original colors"
                for imageView in imageViews {
                    switch imageView.imageColorTransformType {
                    case .imageExtension: imageView.image = imageView.image?.imageWithColor(newColor: nil)
                    case .imageViewExtension: imageView.imageColor = nil
                    case .none: break
                    }
                }
            } else {
                navigationItem.title = "Template colors"
                for imageView in imageViews {
                    switch imageView.imageColorTransformType {
                    case .imageExtension: imageView.image = imageView.image?.imageWithColor(newColor: UIColor.blue)
                    case .imageViewExtension: imageView.imageColor = UIColor.green
                    case .none: break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        get { return _useOriginalColors }
    }

    @objc func colorSwitchButtonTouchedUpInside(_ sender: Any) { useOriginalColors = !useOriginalColors }
}
```

### Storyboard

[image]

### Result

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this in swift with the following code:

```
// language: Swift
let tintedImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"whatever")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate))

tintedImage.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift + Interface builder (storyboard)

If you added the UIImageView in the interface builder:

```
myIcon.image = myIcon.image!.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
myIcon.tintColor = UIColor.red // your color
```

where `myIcon` is an outlet from your storyboard, ex: `@IBOutlet weak var myIcon: UIImageView!`

Answer (score 1):

Change the color of the image in UIImageView:

```
public extension UIImageView {
    func tintImage(color: UIColor) {
        image = image?.tint(color: color)
    }
}
```

Just call the method:

```
imageView.tintImage(color: .red)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to [skywinder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26627433/2704776)

You can also do this on a button:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"];
[myButton setImage:[image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```