# remove white from jpg with smooth edge in objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using the UIImage category from the post below:

[ios: change the colors of a UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396236/ios-change-the-colors-of-a-uiimage)

Works pretty good except there are some jagged edges.  Is there another way to accomplish this but with a smoother edge?

Comment: The post you are linking to is about single color images with transparency, however you title refers to a jpeg, which is an image format without transparency. I'm afraid that color replacement is much more difficult in this case.

Comment: there is some category code that creates a mask using a color with CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors.  Works great but jagged edges most of the time. Was looking for something similar that would have a smooth edge instead

Comment: 1. If u r using UIImageview to display make sure that the UIImage size matches the UIImageView frame size.
2. Image size should be of even size. For example: 64x52, 64-width 52-height.

And also u can check if the images are misaligned in the simulator.
check **debug>color misaligned images**.

Make sure the image view doesn't show yellow or red color.

Hope it helps. Thanks