# iOS Changing half of the image's color

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, core-graphics

I have a single image that looks like this…

[image]

What I have to achieve is that I have to change the color of the lower half of this image..
like this one.. 
[image]

I've tried using `CAGradientLayer`, `Masking` but no luck getting the result..

any help would be great.. Thanks in advance..

**UPDATE 1**

This is what em getting after this code.. One thing i need to add is that image is resized before using..

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

[image]

Comment: Why not just edit the image in a photo editor and add it back to the project? If you want to switch between the two images.. just use two images so it gives the effect you're after?

Comment: actually the size changes of the image regularly

Comment: Are you using a Label to show the text "There" or is it i the image itself.?  If you are using a label to show the text then how about provinding the necessary background color to the UILabel itself.

Comment: yes its a label.. but theres a lot of padding around it…?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396236/ios-change-the-colors-of-a-uiimage/12399760#12399760

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you made me some good challenge with this, but here you go:

Method that return image with bottom half coloured with some colour

```
- (UIImage *)image:(UIImage *)image withBottomHalfOverlayColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) {
        CGFloat imageScale = 1.f;
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
            imageScale = image.scale;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, imageScale);
    }
    else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    }

    [image drawInRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceIn);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);

    CGRect rectToFill = CGRectMake(0.f, image.size.height*0.5f, image.size.width, image.size.height*0.5f);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectToFill);

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Example of use :

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"q.png"];
    image = [self image:image withBottomHalfOverlayColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
    self.imageView.image = image;
```

My results :[image][image]

Comment: just added in question.. plz u can get it from here.

Comment: this is what i've used for resizing `UIImage *bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"TM-Bubbles-Blue"] resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 32, 30, 23) resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeStretch];`

Comment: try to switch the order, colour first resize after

Comment: This worked great for me, thank you so much!.  I translated it into Swift, will post below.

Answer (score 6):

**In Swift 4.** Some Changes

```
func withBottomHalfOverlayColor(myImage: UIImage, color: UIColor) -> UIImage
  {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: myImage.size.width, height: myImage.size.height)


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myImage.size, false, myImage.scale)
    myImage.draw(in: rect)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.sourceIn)

    context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)

    let rectToFill = CGRect(x: 0, y: myImage.size.height*0.5, width: myImage.size.width, height: myImage.size.height*0.5)
    context.fill(rectToFill)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some tricks:

- Use 2 different images and change the whole background.
- Use one background color (light blue) and 2 images, one with the bottom half
  transparent

Comment: i have to calculate the size of the background image and then place it on view

Comment: In my experience, drawing such pixel perfect and complicate composite views is achieved more easily with images and tricks like those ones than by writing very complex drawing code. Also, you should consider making that widget two separate views or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 extension**

```
extension UIImage {
    func withBottomHalfOverlayColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage
      {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)


        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        draw(in: rect)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.sourceIn)

        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)

        let rectToFill = CGRect(x: 0, y: size.height*0.5, width: size.width, height: size.height*0.5)
        context.fill(rectToFill)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
      }
}
```