# How to change a solid color from a PNG without affect transparency?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

This is a great answere [ios: change the colors of a UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396236/ios-change-the-colors-of-a-uiimage)

Here is the call method i trying to use:

```
NSMutableArray *newColors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"0", @"0", @"0", @"0", @"0", @"0", nil];

imgObject001.image = [UIImage changeColorTo:newColors Transparent:imgObject001.image];
```

But it only works with solid color. 
And this image with transparency, when setted, got no size at all, and I get error

> "CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0".

How can I change the color on this PNG with transparency (without affecting the transparency)?

By the way, why the transparent image, begins without size? ( bonus answer hehehe )

Comment: Please share the implementation of your -changeColorTo:Transparent: method—that’s not a standard part of UIKit.

Comment: `-ChangeColorTo:Transparent:` is in the answer lined at the top of the question.

Comment: @BojanG You answer Noah Witherspoon ?? Is that ??