# Changing the color of a certain part of a UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I need to tint only a certain part of a UIImage. In the image below I only need to be able to change the red color to any `UIColor` I have tried a `UIImage+Tint` but it tints the entire image. Does anybody know how I could only change the color of the red part of the image?

[image]

Comment: Try checking this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396236/ios-change-the-colors-of-a-uiimage