# How to replace a given color with another on an opaque UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to change the color of an opaque UIImage. My original image is as follows:

[image]

and I want to convert the image to the following format

[image]

So, basically I want to convert **red** color in the image into **black** (Any other color) color. Above two images are added for better understanding.

Comment: check this.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396236/ios-change-the-colors-of-a-uiimage

Comment: are you simply converting the red areas to black, or extracting the red areas to a new black image?  I ask because the second image doesn't show the shadow that's present in the first

Comment: @Russell: I want to simply convert red area into black.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**I couldn't see any answers on the 'duplicates' (this question shouldn't have been flagged as a duplicate) that will let you replace a given color with another color *and* work on an opaque image, so I decided to add one that would.**

---

I created a `UIImage` category to do this, it basically works by looping through each pixel and detecting how close it is to a given colour, and blends it with your replacement colour if it is.

This will work for images with **both transparency and opaque backgrounds**.

```
@implementation UIImage (UIImageColorReplacement)

-(UIImage*) imageByReplacingColor:(UIColor*)sourceColor withMinTolerance:(CGFloat)minTolerance withMaxTolerance:(CGFloat)maxTolerance withColor:(UIColor*)destinationColor {

    // components of the source color
    const CGFloat* sourceComponents = CGColorGetComponents(sourceColor.CGColor);
    UInt8* source255Components = malloc(sizeof(UInt8)*4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) source255Components[i] = (UInt8)round(sourceComponents[i]*255.0);

    // components of the destination color
    const CGFloat* destinationComponents = CGColorGetComponents(destinationColor.CGColor);
    UInt8* destination255Components = malloc(sizeof(UInt8)*4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) destination255Components[i] = (UInt8)round(destinationComponents[i]*255.0);

    // raw image reference
    CGImageRef rawImage = self.CGImage;

    // image attributes
    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(rawImage);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(rawImage);
    CGRect rect = {CGPointZero, {width, height}};

    // bitmap format
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bytesPerRow = width*4;
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big;

    // data pointer
    UInt8* data = calloc(bytesPerRow, height);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // create bitmap context
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, rect, rawImage);

    // loop through each pixel's components
    for (int byte = 0; byte < bytesPerRow*height; byte += 4) {

        UInt8 r = data[byte];
        UInt8 g = data[byte+1];
        UInt8 b = data[byte+2];

        // delta components
        UInt8 dr = abs(r-source255Components[0]);
        UInt8 dg = abs(g-source255Components[1]);
        UInt8 db = abs(b-source255Components[2]);

        // ratio of 'how far away' each component is from the source color
        CGFloat ratio = (dr+dg+db)/(255.0*3.0);
        if (ratio > maxTolerance) ratio = 1; // if ratio is too far away, set it to max.
        if (ratio < minTolerance) ratio = 0; // if ratio isn't far enough away, set it to min.

        // blend color components
        data[byte] = (UInt8)round(ratio*r)+(UInt8)round((1.0-ratio)*destination255Components[0]);
        data[byte+1] = (UInt8)round(ratio*g)+(UInt8)round((1.0-ratio)*destination255Components[1]);
        data[byte+2] = (UInt8)round(ratio*b)+(UInt8)round((1.0-ratio)*destination255Components[2]);

    }

    // get image from context
    CGImageRef img = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);

    // clean up
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    free(data);
    free(source255Components);
    free(destination255Components);

    UIImage* returnImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img];
    CGImageRelease(img);

    return returnImage;
}

@end
```

**Usage:**

```
UIImage* colaImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cola1.png"];
UIImage* blackColaImage = [colaImage imageByReplacingColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] withMinTolerance:0.5 withMaxTolerance:0.6 withColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]];
```

The `minTolerance` is the point at which pixels will start to blend with the replacement colour (rather than being replaced). The `maxTolerance` is the point at which the pixels will stop being blended.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

The result is a little aliased, but bear in mind that your original image was fairly small. This will work much better with a higher resolution image. You can also play about with the tolerances to get even better results!

Comment: works great! tried out a couple of other solutions but this one is spot on.

Comment: could you rewrite it with Swift 3?

Comment: The best answer for sure. I translated to Swift 3 [replaceColor.swift](http://www.realadsb.com/dl/replaceColor.swift)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this**

```
  theImageView.image = [image  imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
   [theImageView setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

I think something wrong with your image here is my image, it is in white . [image]

here is the change in simulator 
[image]

Comment: Yes it is my tested code and it is working.

Comment: The image in the question has a white background, this will only work on transparent PNGs.

Comment: This is displaying it as black but not actually changing the image.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: First, You need to set your image's Background as transparent with Photoshop or any other tool.

Then use below code.

Easy way,
You need to use rendering mode to change this color.

```
cokeImageView.image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]; // yourimageviewname 
[cokeImageView setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: When I apply above code my entire imageview is converted into black color

Comment: it is worked first you test it. don't give negative marking without testing code. I am always using this method.

Comment: The image in the question has a white background, this will only work on transparent PNGs.

Comment: There is issue in your image

Comment: yes. the actual way in MAC which support PNG format , doesn't have White background in mostly cases. image should be transparent in place of white background.

Comment: @EICaptain yes bro. But i thought it have transparent background.

Comment: I downloaded the image and tried the code it didnt worked @EICaptain i didnt knew it had transparency issues

Comment: @RahulPatel you should try your own project's image.