# How to change tintColor of image in UIButton with imageEdgeInsets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, tintcolor, uiedgeinsets

I I have an UIButton in my objective-c application. My button was modified adding text and image like:

```
- (void)centerButtonAndImageWithSpacing:(CGFloat)spacing {
     CGFloat insetAmount = spacing / 2.0;
     self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -insetAmount, 0, insetAmount);
     self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, insetAmount, 0, -insetAmount);
     self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, insetAmount, 0, insetAmount);
}
```

And then I add the image with this code:

```
[self.myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I want change the tintColor of the image, but when I try change this, my code isn't work:

```
[self.myButton setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

I'm trying use this code, but didn't work:

```
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
icon.image = [img imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
icon.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

I have this:
[image]

I want get it:
[image]

How could I change the color of the imageButton?

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396236/ios-change-the-colors-of-a-uiimage

Answer (score 3):

We can apply the desired color for the transparent icons with the following way.

1.Drag the image on `Assets.xcassets` and In asset attribute inspector change the Render as attribute to `Template Image`.

[image]

2.And set the required tint color like below way.

```
icon.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to change tintColor property was setImage with renderingMode:

```
 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate
```

With this code:

```
[self.myButton setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageButton.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Then set image to button with this code we can set the tintColor property correctly:

```
 self.myButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the UIButtonType to UIButtonTypeCustom in Interface Builder or programmatically with

```
 UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Change the attributes on your own and recreate the rounded corners

```
myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
myButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
myButton.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
```

let me know the status ..

Comment: How can I apply this, if my button is an IBOutlet added to storyboard?

Comment: @user3745888 You will see the Type when you will select button in storyboard just change it to custom

Comment: I have add this, but this change the background, this don't change the color of uiimage..

Answer (score 1):

Create a layer and set your desired coloured and mask in on your ImageView in your button like this.

```
for (UIView *view in myButton.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
            mask.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
            view.layer.mask = mask;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 and 4.2**

```
let img = UIImage.init(named: "buttonName")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
            btn.setImage(img, for: .normal)
            btn.tintColor = .gray

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
let examButton = UIButton(image: UIImage(systemName: "rectangle.dock")!, tintColor: .systemRed, target: self, action: #selector(showExamController))

examButton.setTitleColor(.label, for: .normal)
examButton.setTitle("   12K", for: .normal)
```