# How to color a stretchable UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uikit

I would like to color an UIImage stretchable but I cannot make it work.
With the help of this post : [How to change the color of an UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755576/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-uiimage) I've successfully colored my UIImage but when I make it stretchable, the color isn't set on the 'new' frame.

Here is how I set my color using a category :

```
+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name withColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
    if (color == nil)
        return image;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, image.CGImage);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage
                               scale:1.0
                         orientation:UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated...

Comment: Can you paste how you create the colored image and then make it stretchable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name withColor:(UIColor *)theColor
{
    UIImage *baseImage = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(baseImage.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect area = CGRectMake(0, 0, baseImage.size.width, baseImage.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -area.size.height);
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextClipToMask(ctx, area, baseImage.CGImage);
    [theColor set];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, area);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, area, baseImage.CGImage);
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an image in your bundle, and you color it using the above, which does not modify the original image but returns a new image. This new image is a normal image, meaning the colors you see are the actual bits in the image. If you now create a new stretchable image from the newly created image, not the original, it should be the correct color.

If not create a small demo project and post it on DropBox and let us take a look at it.