# Change color of png in buttons - ios

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a set of icons that I've created that are transparent white PNGs:

[image]

And what I'd like to do is be able to tint them to other colors. Such as blue, grey, etc.

I've noticed that 'clicked/tapped' they change automatically to a grey. So I assume I can change that grey to whatever I like either with a tap or its normal state:

[image]

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Following code will set tint colour for normal state of button:

For Swift 4 and newer:

```
let origImage = UIImage(named: "imageName")
let tintedImage = origImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
btn.setImage(tintedImage, for: .normal)
btn.tintColor = .red
```

You can change tint colour according to your need when state changes for button.

---

#### Older versions

For Swift 3:

```
let origImage = UIImage(named: "imageName")
let tintedImage = origImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
btn.setImage(tintedImage, forState: .normal)
btn.tintColor = .redColor
```

For Swift 2:
see revision history.

Comment: Wonderful! But how do you revert back to the original image (un-tinted)?

Comment: @Marsman if you look at my solution originaImage represents the original image and tintedImage represents tinted version of original image, so you are not replacing the original Image but creating new version of it and you will have two version of same image that you can use as per your need

Comment: not working in iOS 11 with xcode 9.1. When Add the tint color, it is completly change the color of the imageView.

Comment: The various edits have introduced inaccuracies in this answer.

Answer (score 33):

I found the easiest approach below,

Open assetcatalog and select the image then go to **attributes inspector** and change `Render As` to `Template Image` as below

[image]

Then add below code in button Action method

```
yourButton.tintColor = .gray
```

Answer (score 23):

Swift 4 or 5

```
extension UIButton{

    func setImageTintColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        let tintedImage = self.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.setImage(tintedImage, for: .normal)
        self.tintColor = color
    }

}
```

Use:

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "image_name"), for: .normal) // You can set image direct from Storyboard
button.setImageTintColor(UIColor.white)
```

Comment: there is no any method of setImageTintColor for UIbutton view

Comment: It is an extension of UIButton. I have created on above.

Answer (score 14):

iOS 7 introduced a property called tintColor for views (including UIImageView). However you also need to set the rendering type on the UIImage for this to have any effect.

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImage *tintedImage = [originalImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:tintedImage];

imageView.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

This should produce the effect you are after in a default state.

Answer (score 11):

If you are setting the image for a button, just go to attributes inspector and change the button type to system. Then set the image and change the tint color. The color of the image will change. If it did not take place, check the button type.

Answer (score 10):

For change tint of image (**pick**, **classical image**, **photo**) use that  :

**Example image :**
[image]
[image]

**Swift 2**

```
public extension UIImage {
    /**
     Tint, Colorize image with given tint color<br><br>
     This is similar to Photoshop's "Color" layer blend mode<br><br>
     This is perfect for non-greyscale source images, and images that have both highlights and shadows that should be preserved<br><br>
     white will stay white and black will stay black as the lightness of the image is preserved<br><br>

     <img src="http://yannickstephan.com/easyhelper/tint1.png" height="70" width="120"/>

     **To**

     <img src="http://yannickstephan.com/easyhelper/tint2.png" height="70" width="120"/>

     - parameter tintColor: UIColor

     - returns: UIImage
     */
    public func tintPhoto(tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {

        return modifiedImage { context, rect in
            // draw black background - workaround to preserve color of partially transparent pixels
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, .Normal)
            UIColor.blackColor().setFill()
            CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

            // draw original image
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, .Normal)
            CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.CGImage)

            // tint image (loosing alpha) - the luminosity of the original image is preserved
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, .Color)
            tintColor.setFill()
            CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

            // mask by alpha values of original image
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, .DestinationIn)
            CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.CGImage)
        }
    }
    /**
     Tint Picto to color

     - parameter fillColor: UIColor

     - returns: UIImage
     */
    public func tintPicto(fillColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {

        return modifiedImage { context, rect in
            // draw tint color
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, .Normal)
            fillColor.setFill()
            CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

            // mask by alpha values of original image
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, .DestinationIn)
            CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.CGImage)
        }
    }
    /**
     Modified Image Context, apply modification on image

     - parameter draw: (CGContext, CGRect) -> ())

     - returns: UIImage
     */
    private func modifiedImage(@noescape draw: (CGContext, CGRect) -> ()) -> UIImage {

        // using scale correctly preserves retina images
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        let context: CGContext! = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        assert(context != nil)

        // correctly rotate image
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

        let rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height)

        draw(context, rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

**UPD**

**Swift 3**

```
extension UIImage {

    /**
     Tint, Colorize image with given tint color<br><br>
     This is similar to Photoshop's "Color" layer blend mode<br><br>
     This is perfect for non-greyscale source images, and images that have both highlights and shadows that should be preserved<br><br>
     white will stay white and black will stay black as the lightness of the image is preserved<br><br>

     <img src="http://yannickstephan.com/easyhelper/tint1.png" height="70" width="120"/>

     **To**

     <img src="http://yannickstephan.com/easyhelper/tint2.png" height="70" width="120"/>

     - parameter tintColor: UIColor

     - returns: UIImage
     */
    func tintPhoto(_ tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {

        return modifiedImage { context, rect in
            // draw black background - workaround to preserve color of partially transparent pixels
            context.setBlendMode(.normal)
            UIColor.black.setFill()
            context.fill(rect)

            // draw original image
            context.setBlendMode(.normal)
            context.draw(cgImage!, in: rect)

            // tint image (loosing alpha) - the luminosity of the original image is preserved
            context.setBlendMode(.color)
            tintColor.setFill()
            context.fill(rect)

            // mask by alpha values of original image
            context.setBlendMode(.destinationIn)
            context.draw(context.makeImage()!, in: rect)
        }
    }

    /**
     Tint Picto to color

     - parameter fillColor: UIColor

     - returns: UIImage
     */
    func tintPicto(_ fillColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {

        return modifiedImage { context, rect in
            // draw tint color
            context.setBlendMode(.normal)
            fillColor.setFill()
            context.fill(rect)

            // mask by alpha values of original image
            context.setBlendMode(.destinationIn)
            context.draw(cgImage!, in: rect)
        }
    }

    /**
     Modified Image Context, apply modification on image

     - parameter draw: (CGContext, CGRect) -> ())

     - returns: UIImage
     */
    fileprivate func modifiedImage(_ draw: (CGContext, CGRect) -> ()) -> UIImage {

        // using scale correctly preserves retina images
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        let context: CGContext! = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        assert(context != nil)

        // correctly rotate image
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

        draw(context, rect)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }

}
```

Comment: can u tell me how to use this methods means how to call them?

Comment: This does not work at all for me. I have a PNG set as the button's image. When I use either tintPhoto or tintPicto, they just don't work.

Comment: dit you add your image withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate) ? @Moebius

Comment: Yes, and when I use either of the tint methods all I see is the color. I even set the alpha of the color to 0.5 and I still see just the color. Swift 4

Comment: Ok apply alpha after the tint @Moebius

Answer (score 10):

You can use this extension:

```swift
import UIKit

extension CGContext {

    func fill(_ rect: CGRect,
              with mask: CGImage,
              using color: CGColor) {

        saveGState()
        defer { restoreGState() }

        translateBy(x: 0.0, y: rect.size.height)
        scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        setBlendMode(.normal)

        clip(to: rect, mask: mask)

        setFillColor(color)
        fill(rect)
    }
}

extension UIImage {

    func filled(with color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.size)
        guard let mask = self.cgImage else { return self }

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let rendererFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
            rendererFormat.scale = self.scale

            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: rect.size,
                                                   format: rendererFormat)
            return renderer.image { context in
                context.cgContext.fill(rect,
                                       with: mask,
                                       using: color.cgColor)
            }
        } else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,
                                                   false,
                                                   self.scale)
            defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }

            guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return self }

            context.fill(rect,
                         with: mask,
                         using: color.cgColor)
            return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() ?? self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me either. When I use this method, all I see is the color, not the image tinted that color.

Answer (score 7):

If you use asset catalogs you can set the image asset itself to render in template mode.  After that you can set the tintColor of the button in Interface Builder (or in code) and it should take.

Comment: This is the best approach if you're using the same image in multiple places as you only set the image to template mode one time in the Asset Catalog.

Comment: This approach did not work for me. When I set a PNG as a template image and then set the tint color, the image is replaced by the tint color.

Comment: This is the best approach for me also. Thanks a lot. Simple easy reusable...

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4

```
    let origImage = UIImage(named: "check")
    let tintedImage = origImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    buttons[0].setImage(tintedImage, for: .normal)
    buttons[0].tintColor = .red
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use asset catalogs you can set the image asset itself to render in template mode. After that you can set the tintColor of the button in Interface Builder (or in code) and it should take.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 and 4.2

```
let img = UIImage.init(named: "buttonName")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
            btn.setImage(img, for: .normal)
            btn.tintColor = .gray
```

[image]