# Change color of UITabBar Icon

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uicolor

I want to change the UI Tab Bar Icon colour to the values: Red: 0.75, Green: 1.0, Blue: 1.0, Alpha: 1.0 and to white when the Icon is not selected.

Till now I thought this is how you do it:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().finishedSelectedImage([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 0.75, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)], forState: UIControlState.Selected)

    UITabBarItem.appearance().finishedUnselectedImage([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

The code above is in my delegate.

Now I have put this code:

```
import UIKit

class UITabBarViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var testImage = UIImage(named: "22274")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
    testImageView.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    testImageView.image = testImage

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}
```

Into my tab bar view controller cocco touch file. I don't know why I'm getting an error still

Comment: is there an image that you want to color, or just text?

Comment: You set the tint color

Comment: I have no images at the moment but im talking about the future. I can see it in the 'more' tab bar icon that it is grey and it doesn't go well with my blue background. @DánielNagy

Comment: How do I set the colour of the icons then? @soulshined

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755576/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-uiimage this is an objective c example, but look at the second answer, not the accepted one

Comment: Can you convert it into swift and tell me where to put that code please? @DánielNagy

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had traverse all the sub-controllers of UITabbarController, and then set the TabBarItem's color or tint color of each controller, it does work.

Answer (score 0):

If the tabbaritem has an image, you can set its color by:

```
var testImage = UIImage(named: "someImageName")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
testImageView.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
testImageView.image = testImage
```

Comment: Where do I add this? In the delegates or the actual view controller?

Comment: in the actual viewcontollers, for example in the viewDidLoad function

Comment: which view controller? The one I made for the Tab Bar Navigation Controller? or just any screen?

Comment: The best is if you put to the one that you created for the tab bar, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying: Use of unresolved identifier 'testImageView'

Comment: Of course you have, you should write there the name of the image you want to color, if you have any

Answer (score 0):

I think It's not available to make it, you can just get an image in the color you want and use it in the UITabbar
but regarding to change the all TabBar colors you can use the below in your AppDelegate in Func:

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

Lines To be added:

```
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2000651062, green: 0.1960035861, blue: 0.2000851929, alpha: 1)

UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2000651062, green: 0.1960035861, blue: 0.2000851929, alpha: 1)

UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7415059209, green: 0.5448099971, blue: 0.5051562786, alpha: 1)
```

**Note:** You can change colors depending on your App

Check the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wESVH.png

and have a happy coding day

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by @Menaim, I found the solution in my code base in the AppDelegate. Change the window?.tintColor to the desired color.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

      func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
                                                                      launchOptions:
           [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? -> Bool
           window?.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.75, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
           UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
}
```