# Objective-C animation, orbit ring animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have searched around for the orbit rings animation, but cannot find what I need.
I am attaching screenshot what I want exactly.

[image]

I want all the orbit rings are animating together with their own path at same time and white object is moving around of them.

1. It can possible if I take images of all rings like gif image has 15-20 images and animate all images with timer, but I don't want to take so many images because I have to change the color of ring also.
2. So please provide me the best way to do the following animation.

Comment: I'm not quite sure exactly how to do this animation, but it probably involves creating many circles and rotating them in a 3d plane. Also, If you have the image in png format, you will be able to change the colors of the ring with a UIImageView (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26627433/2791584)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this programmatically, you will have draw the shape of the electron paths and fill them in.

This can be done using Bezier curves. Cocoa contains calls to make Bezier curves, fill them in, and apply custom animations. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html for drawing filled Bezier curves, and http://lafosca.cat/smooth-and-custom-animations-in-ios/ for some hints on animating them efficiently.