# iOS: How to replace a specific color by another in a UIImage of a TabBar (select and unselect)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uigraphicscontext

I would like to replace a color by another in my UITabBar when it is selected. The aim is to get one image that I can change the colors programmatically.

How can I do it?

```
let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: menuName, image: unselectedImage, selectedImage: selectedImage)
```

I checked that tickets with no success:
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10755807/3581620), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40884483/3581620)
[image]

Comment: have you tried to set the render mode to Template in .xcaccess or programaticly and change the tint color to the imageView where the image is rendered or change the tabor tintColor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same kind of problem. You should create a background white png, and put the other image on top
with a translucent background png.

(And I think that you should use image with better quality because your pics look weird)

```
                let iconWhite: UIImage? = self.load(fileName: "APP/icones/\(iconName).png")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
                        
                        
        //UNSELECT IMAGE
                        var unselectedImgBack = UIImage(named: "white.png")
                        var unselectedImgFront = iconWhite?.overlayImage(color: UIColor.black)
                        
                        let size = unselectedImgFront?.size
                        unselectedImgBack = unselectedImgBack?.resized(to: size!)
                        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size!)
                        let areaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size!.width, height: size!.height)
                        unselectedImgBack!.draw(in: areaSize)
                        unselectedImgFront!.draw(in: areaSize, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1)
                        unselectedImgFront = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
                        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                        
                        let unselectedImage =  unselectedImgFront!.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
                        
        //SELECT IMAGE
                        
                        var selectedImgBack = UIImage(named: "white.png")
                        var selectedImgFront = iconWhite
                        
                        let scanner2 = Scanner(string: color)
                        var value: UInt64 = 0
                        
                        if scanner2.scanHexInt64(&value) {
                            print("Decimal: \(value)")
                            print("Hex: 0x\(String(value, radix: 16))")
                        }
                        selectedImgBack = selectedImgBack?.overlayImage(color: UIColor.init(rgb: Int(value)))

                        selectedImgBack = selectedImgBack?.resized(to: size!)
                        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size!)
                        selectedImgBack!.draw(in: areaSize)
                        selectedImgFront!.draw(in: areaSize, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 0.8)
                        selectedImgFront = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
                        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                        
                        let selectedImage = selectedImgFront!.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. (for the pics, I will forward your comment to the graphist guy :D)